# Multiple forms using same javascript method

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I'm a little stuck with something i've been trying to do.

I've been trying to get multiple forms (six) to use a javascript method that i have. These forms have text input values and should be checked, then passed to a php file then AJAX is used to update the page with confirmation or an error.

For this example i'll use only two forms, these are my forms

```
<div class="trade_info_1">
            <h2>Market #1</h2>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="market_1">Market: </label><input type="text" name="market_1" id="market_1" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="button" name="button1" id="button1" onclick="check_update_selection()">Update Market!</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input type="hidden" name="market_number" id="market_number" value="1" />
                <div id="market_1_output">output</div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="trade_info_2">
            <h2>Market #2</h2>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="market_2">Market: </label><input type="text" name="market_2" id="market_2" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="button" name="button2" id="button2" onclick="check_update_selection()">Update Market!</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input type="hidden" name="market_number" id="market_number" value="2" />
                <div id="market_2_output">output</div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Now  and  is where the AJAX will update the page. This is the method i have already (JS)

```
function check_update_selection() 
 {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
{
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

console.log('Market value: ' + document.getElementById('market_number').value);

if(document.getElementById('market_number').value == 1)
{
    var market = document.getElementById('market_1').value;;
    var market_number = 1;
    var html_element = 'market_1';
}
else if(document.getElementById('market_number').value == 2)
{
    var market = document.getElementById('market_1').value;
    var market_number = 2;
    var html_element = 'market_2';
}

xhr.open('POST', 'update_market.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
var obj = {market: market};
xhr.send("data=" + JSON.stringify(obj));
xhr.onreadystatechange=function() 
{
    if (xhr.readyState==4) 
    {
        if(market_number == 1)
        {
            document.getElementById("market_1_output").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
        else if(market_number == 2)
        {
            document.getElementById("market_2_output").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

I won't include the php because all it does it echo the word "TEST".

The first form works perfectly, however, the second form doesn't, it seems to up date the first form. so i used console.log(); and found that every time i submit the second form it seems to submit the the fields from the first form.

Am i going the right way about this or is there something i am missing?

Also i am learning javascript as we speak so my knowledge of the platform isn't the best so please point out any mistakes i've made.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 2 elements shouldn't have the same id..., so you can't use 2 times "market_number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put in the same page 2 elements with the same id (market_number):

```
<input type="hidden" name="market_number" id="market_number" value="2" />
```

a better solution might be to define the main function check_update_selection a parameter and then just call it with that param from each form:

```
function check_update_selection(number)
```

and from your HTML call it with the right number:

```
 onclick="check_update_selection(1)"
 onclick="check_update_selection(2)"
```

Comment: Ahh, i thought i could get away with it because they were different forms..... I'll give this a shot now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First having multiple forms in the same page pointing to a same action is a poor practice. 
Second id of the elements should be unique.

If you are a beginner then validate the HTML in w3c validator you'll come to learn a lot from that itself.

Comment: @ragebunny: from your code it looks like your action is going to be the same irrespective of the forms. Then why do you need two forms?

Comment: @ragebunny: Sorry i haven't mentioned that in my answer before. But the same action thing was the one that caught my eye and hence the statement

Comment: Well, have multiple forms kind of looks better for the user i think, so they are all separate, maybe it would be best practice to use one form but multiple buttons? Is that a better way or would just one big button be best?